# Export Module in next.config.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

please how do I combine these 2 and export

```
module.exports = withCSS(withImages())

module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    API_URL: 'api_url'
  },
}
```

Comment: Please share more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-configuration). You pass your plugins, and then the config.

```
module.exports = withCSS(withImages({
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        API_URL: 'api_url'
    },
}));
```

Edit: [Example Usage](https://github.com/ninetynine/next-fonts#usage).

Answer (score 1):

You can expose it as a part of your configuration by attaching a property `withCSS` to the exported config object.

```
module.exports = {
  withCSS: withImages(),
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    API_URL: 'api_url'
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put them together in your final object :

```
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    API_URL: 'api_url'
  },
  myCSS: withCSS(withImages())
}
```

You now just have to add '.myCSS' next to you imported variable to access the second element

Answer (score 1):

You can use [next-compose-plugins](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins) library to add multiple plugins in `config.next.js` file:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const sass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

module.exports = withPlugins([
  [sass],
]);
```